# Swift: Can't access IBOutlet in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift

I create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass with a `@IBOutlet` property 'label', but it's nil when I access it in `viewDidLoad` function.

**TableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var cell = TableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:nil)
        println(cell.label) // nil
    }

}
```

**TableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell:UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

**Main.storyboard**

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="TableViewCell" id="cNV-ZQ-ovR" customClass="TableViewCell" customModule="SimpleTable" customModuleProvider="target">
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="cNV-ZQ-ovR" id="3Qh-aQ-Ys2">
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <subviews>
            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="H9h-90-Iff">
                <rect key="frame" x="15" y="12" width="252" height="21"/>
                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
            </label>
        </subviews>
    </tableViewCellContentView>
    <connections>
        <outlet property="label" destination="H9h-90-Iff" id="tMj-pZ-Ad2"/>
    </connections>
</tableViewCell>
```

**Xcode 6.1 build6A1052d**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using prototype cells in a storyboard and defining the cell's contents and connections there, you have to get a copy of that "prepared" cell from the table view. You can't just create a new object of the cell and expect it to work (you're getting a "raw" instance instead without any connections made)

What you want to do is set an identifier of the prototype cell in Interface Builder (it's in attributes inspector). Then, to get a new instance of the cell, simply:

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier") as TableViewCell
```

In your case, you're making this call inside of the table view controller, so just omit `tableView.`